# Maximality statements that cannot be proved using $\mathsf{ZL}$

Tags: lo.logic, big-list

What are examples for maximality statements that cannot be proved using Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: I think the title and the actual question don't fit together.

Comment: "existence of ultrafilters" (or BPI) is an answer to the  question in the title, but not to the actual question.

Answer (score 5):

A statement I like very much is:

> > Any compact topology is contained in a maximal compact topology.

A direct application of Zorn's Lemma doesn't work, as the following argument shows. Consider $\omega$ as ground set, and set $\tau_n := \cal{P}(\{0,\ldots,n\}) \cup \{\omega\}$ for $n\in\omega$. Then $\{\tau_n:n\in \omega\}$ is a chain of compact topologies, but its supremum is the discrete topology on $\omega$, which is not compact.

Despite failure of a direct application of $\mathsf{ZL}$, Martin Maria Kovar proved [here](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/volltexte/2005/118/pdf/04351.KovarMartin1.Paper.118.pdf) that every compact topology is contained in a maximal compact topology, settling an open question that was asked by D. E. Cameron in 1977.